# Finding numeric characters using wildcards in countif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a countif function, using which I want to count those cells which have a numeric character anywhere.

```
Column A
Rich-Dilg-street 3
I have 4 apples
I have seven dogs
```

How do I write the `countif` criteria using wildcards in such a way that I can count those which have a numeric character? In the above example, the answer should 2 (1 and 2 not 3)

Comment: Are the numbers always single digit?  If not it will be difficult with a countif not to count each digit as its own return.  If that is the case regex would probably be best.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes. in my usecases I need only count any one digit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) with multiple wildcarded criteria.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"*0*","*1*","*2*","*3*","*4*","*5*","*6*","*7*","*8*","*9*"}))
```

As pointed out by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) you can reduce the typing with,

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, "*"&{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&"*"))
```

Comment: less typing: `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,"*" & {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} & "*"))`  I was just waiting on a response. :)

Comment: Good catch! I'll edit to address that if you don't mind. (I'll owe you one)

Comment: Simply Beautiful :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I got giddy at seeing this too. It's amazing what one can find beautiful and inspiring in this life :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But why do you include the sum function? Isn't countif supposed the count the cells?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak - The braces are a constant array of values. The COUNTIF returns an array of counts (one for each in the constant array). You need SUM to collect all of the returns into a single one. Use the Formulas, [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) command and step through the process to understand further.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
For Each Cell in Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
    For x = 1 to Len(Cell.Value)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Cell.Value, x, 1)) Then
            Cell.Offset(0,1).Value = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count, find and countif to get the desired result.

If the strings are in column A then

```
=count(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0 will return True else false
```

Now, count the total number of true values using countif

```
=countif(B:B,True)
```

I am assuming that the strings contains non-negative numbers.

[image]